# Gulp script crashes with Node 8, but works fine with Node 6

Tags: node.js, gulp

Since updating to Node 8 (I tried 8.6.0 and 8.9.4) I get the error `Error: Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'` when running any task of my Gulp build script (using Gulp 3.9.1). When I downgrade back to Node 6 (6.4.0), the scripts work again. The error is not caused by the scripts themselves, it also occurs when running an empty dummy task. I use the Node version manager n.

All similar questions which I found solve this issue by upgrading npm, which I did as well (5.6.0), without success. I also updated all installed modules to the latest version.

From the stack trace I can see that the module graceful-fs seems to cause the problem, but this is a dependency of Gulp itself, so I cannot get rid of it. Is this a compatibility issue of Gulp with the newer Node versions?

The full error output:

```
module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:31:26
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/project/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:11:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
```

Comment: Gulp works fine on node 8. All I can suggest is `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`. Can you try that?

Comment: @mingos That helped, thanks! I apparently only performed an incremental install before, which seems to be a bad idea when changing Node versions.